# Sharepoint Subsite access issue

Tags: permissions, 2016, unique

We have created a custom web template for SharePoint 2016 . When we are creating a site from the same template , all the access are working fine . After creating the subsite from the same template and if we break the site inheritance of subsite and give any user access on the subsite , user is not able to access the subsite .
We think that the issue is because , subsite is still inheriting the parent Site master page library access . Because if we give read access on the parent site master page library to the subsite user , he is able to access the subsite .

Any kind of help will be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when the inheritance is broken, all the default user groups(permissions) are removed and you are adding new user/group. And also the Root site doesn't have any visitor group with All Authenticated users added. Then in that it would fail.Check whether Style Resource Readers group is present or deleted. And your question contains answer.